# How to sum a row in a matrix

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Write the method:

```
public int sumRow(int[][] matrix, int row)
```

that sums row `row` in the 2D array called matrix.

Given:

```
public void run()
{
    System.out.println(sumRow(new int[][]{{70,93,68,78,83},{68,89,91,93,72},{98,68,69,79,88}}, 2));
    System.out.println(sumRow(new int[][]{{1,1,1}, {2,2,2}, {3,3,3}}, 0));
    System.out.println(sumRow(new int[][]{{2,4,6,8,10}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {10,20,30,40,50}}, 2));
}
```

So far I have:

```
public int sumRow(int[][] matrix, int row)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + matrix[j][i];
        }   
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The outputs I get are 714, 18, and 78 when they should be 402, 3, and 150. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're currently trying to sum all of the elements in the 2D array when you were asked to sum a specific row within the 2D array. In this case, you only need one for loop to traverse a single row like you would traverse a single array. The loop would start at the first element, `matrix[row][0]` and run until the last element, `matrix[row][matrix[row].length - 1]` since `matrix[row].length` is the number of columns/elements in that specific row of the matrix. Therefore, `matrix[row].length - 1` would be the index of the last element in `matrix[row]`. Here's what it should look like,

```
public int sumRow(int[][] matrix, int row)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix[row].length; i++)
    {
        sum += matrix[row][i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int sumRow(int[][] matrix, int row)
{
    int sum = 0;

    int colSize = matrix[row].length;


    for(int j = 0; j < colSize; j++){
        sum += matrix[row][j];
    }   

    return sum;
}
```

***HINT***

Length of **row**:

```
int row = matrix.length;
```

Length of **column** :

```
int col = matrix[0].length;
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java Streams can be done very elegantly:

```
public static int sumRow2(int[][] matrix, int row) {
    return  Arrays.stream(matrix[row]).sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the internal loop, modify the condition to:

```
for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
```

and then switch `i` and `j` in the sum

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with your second `for` loop's condition , `matrix.length` is the length of first dimension , for the second dimension it looks like `matrix[i].length`

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
         sum = sum + matrix[i][j];
     }   
}
```

i prefer to use `sum+=matrix[i][j]` instead of `sum = sum + matrix[i][j]`

calculating for **one** row :

```
for(int j = 0; j < matrix[row].length; j++){
    sum = sum + matrix[row][j];
}
```

just **note** that row's range is from `0` to `matrix.length-1`

Comment: Your solution gives the total sum, not the row sum.

Comment: @DYZ are you sure we are reading the same title ? what does `How to sum all rows in a matrix` mean ?

Comment: The title seems to contradict the rest of the question, including the function prototype.

Comment: And the expected/desired output.

Answer (score -1):

You need to reference the second dimension of the array for j.

```
//ex: first dimension is matrix.length
//second dimension is matrix[any index in the first dimension].length
//and this cycle would continue with more and more [num] on the end

public int sumRow(int[][] matrix, int row)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix**[0]**.length; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + matrix[j][i];
        }   
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: How do you use `row`?

Comment: What is the point of having row? If you are specifying only one dimension of the array, then why have nested for loops?

Comment: That's what the OP is asking for.