# How do I get the sum of a row in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array as listen in the code below and I must use the method `sumRow` but im not sure how to do it, most tutorials online are of no help to me. I know it seems easy but if someone could help or explain it to me that would be awesome
code:

```
public class Sum
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] array = {{32, 4, 14, 65, 23, 6},
                        {4, 2, 53, 31, 765, 34},
                        {64235, 23, 522, 124, 42, 64}};
    }
    
    public static int sumRow(int[][] array, int row)
    {
        //This is where the sumRow method is supposed to be made.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify problem you are having which is stopping you from finishing or even starting writing your code? Do you know how to call methods? Do you know how to iterate over elements in array? Do you know how to calculate sum of some elements?

Comment: i dont know how to make a method that adds up the row.

Comment: That is just rephrasing "but im not sure how to do it" which doesn't clarify anything. Please reread my comment.

Comment: I don't know how to make a method to make a sum of the row, This is why I need help. I'm sorry I don't understand your question dude I really am.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum a row in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926972/how-to-sum-a-row-in-a-matrix)

Comment: yes @null_awe thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class Sum {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[][] array = {{32, 4, 14, 65, 23, 6},
                    {4, 2, 53, 31, 765, 34},
                    {64235, 23, 522, 124, 42, 64}};
        }

        public static int sumRow(int[][] array, int row) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
                sum += array[row][col];
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Arrays.stream(arr).sum()`:

```
public static int sumRow(int[][] array, int row) {
    if (row < 0 || row >= array.length) return -1; // row is not valid
    return Arrays.stream(array[row]).sum();
}
```

Comment: sadly that didn't work, Arrays wasn't "declared or is out of Scope" do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: @DevCooperMullen You would need to add `import java.util.Arrays;` or `import java.util.*`. But honestly I would encourage you to not use built-in solutions but create your own using loops.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the row of the array and add each element to `sum` where `int sum` has been initialized with `0`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        int[][] array = { { 32, 4, 14, 65, 23, 6 }, 
                            { 4, 2, 53, 31, 765, 34 }, 
                            { 64235, 23, 522, 124, 42, 64 } };

        // Test
        System.out.println(sumRow(array, 0));
        System.out.println(sumRow(array, 1));
        System.out.println(sumRow(array, 2));
        System.out.println(sumRow(array, 5));
        System.out.println(sumRow(array, -1));
    }

    public static int sumRow(int[][] array, int row) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        int sum = 0;
        if (row >= 0 && row < array.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array[row].length; i++) {
                sum += array[row][i];
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The row number should be >=0 and <" + array.length);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
144
889
65010
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The row number should be >=0 and <3
    at Main.sumRow(Main.java:22)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

**Another demo (with exception handled):**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        int[][] array = { { 32, 4, 14, 65, 23, 6 }, 
                            { 4, 2, 53, 31, 765, 34 },
                            { 64235, 23, 522, 124, 42, 64 } };

        // Test
        for (int i = -1; i < 4; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Sum of row, " + i + ": " + sumRow(array, i));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static int sumRow(int[][] array, int row) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        int sum = 0;
        if (row >= 0 && row < array.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array[row].length; i++) {
                sum += array[row][i];
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The row number should be >=0 and <" + array.length);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The row number should be >=0 and <3
Sum of row, 0: 144
Sum of row, 1: 889
Sum of row, 2: 65010
The row number should be >=0 and <3
```

Comment: This worked great! thank you very much my friend!

Comment: You are most welcome. Wish you success!